# My BLDC motor is stuttering and I have no idea why

Tags: arduino, batteries, motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm driving 2 BLDC motors with two ESCs, the motors and the ESCs are powered by an external LiPo battery and the Arduino is powered via usb. The motors work with pulses between 1000 and 2000 microseconds but during testing (where we accelerate them from 1000 to 2000) the motors stop after about 1350 and before that they stutter like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kmBT.jpg

Comment: What modes are the ESC's running?

Comment: Just did a factory reset to be sure, still does the same thing

Comment: it almost like it sounds like you have a current capacity issue, but an oscilloscope is needed to really further trouble shoot the pwm issue. But since this is a diy project thing, I would suspect crystallized (cold) solder joints first if the ESC (motor controller) is rated and typically used for that motor

Comment: After checking the manual, could it be that the frequency settings for the ESC are off? In their default state its 8kHz which the manual says is for 2 pole motors and supposedly these are 3 pole motors.

Comment: We will try to get rid of the solder joints using bullet connectors